# How to programmatically get the list of Trusted Publishers?

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office

Within the Microsoft Office Trust Center, there is a list of Trusted Publishers.

Is there any way we can programmatically get the list of Trusted Publishers via the .NET  Framework or Office Word Object Model?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, good luck!